# UnboundLocalError triggered during the deployment of a salt minion

Tags: python, git, salt-stack

During a minion deployment, a `UnboundLocalError` is raised by the `git` library used as a dependency of `salt`

```
An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/state.py", line 1594, in call
    **cdata['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1491, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/states/git.py", line 519, in latest
    if remote_rev_type == 'sha1':
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'remote_rev_type' referenced before assignment
```

It is very unclear to know what happen here. Any clue?

Comment: Minions? MINIONS! Could... Could you be Gru?

Comment: Jokes aside, an `UnboundLocalError` is sort of like a syntax error. It pops up when you trying to call a variable before you've ever given it a value.

Comment: @Zizouz212 not quite that kind of minions :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 I get that. But I don't know why this error happen when every other repository is successfully deployed

Comment: I wouldn't really be sure, but I can tell you why the error popped up. That's about it. Maybe someone else who's familiar with this will be able to help out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the [salt-stack](/questions/tagged/salt-stack) library. Variable `remote_rev_type` was not initialized in all execution paths.

From the looks of the [current salt-stack source code](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/7fdc73136c8413a98413ab1aa83ed4065e5eb2ff/salt/states/git.py#L715), I'd say it has been fixed.